# landscape mode in tablet only

Tags: android, landscape, tablet

My app has to support landscape/portrait mode only for tablets, phones will only support portrait mode. What is the best way to implement this?

Options that I am considering:

a) using two apk files, one for phones and one for tablets. The one for phone will lock landscape mode in the manifest

2) using one apk file. Detect that device is a phone, lock landscape mode inside each activity.

any advice will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Use [Fragments API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html), it was design to handle such problems efficiently.

Comment: the app is almost done. Fragments would require to redo the UI. This is not an option. Thanks

Comment: I had the same issue, and just wrote a blog entry on this subject, where I give three different solutions.
http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2011/08/orientation-for-both-phones-and-tablets.html

Comment: This solution worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60381441/7826494

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a SuperClass for activities and implement this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9629127/710162 on, for example, onCreate().